# Filter rows that are matched on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, stringr

I have the following data:

```
dput(output[1:20])
structure(list(number_of_cols = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L), number_of_rows = c(17258L, 17258L, 20059L, 20059L, 16943L, 
16943L, 19090L, 19090L, 17846L, 17846L, 18879L, 18879L, 21076L, 
21076L, 19978L, 19978L, 16625L, 16660L, 15938L, 15938L), name_of_file = c("Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 01_35_01.902191_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 01_35_01.902191_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 02_35_11.367056_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 02_35_11.367056_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 03_35_20.855642_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 03_35_20.855642_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 04_35_30.251926_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 04_35_30.251926_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 05_35_39.708837_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 05_35_39.708837_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 06_35_49.255905_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 06_35_49.255905_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 07_35_58.696052_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 07_35_58.696052_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 18_04_05.227985_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 18_04_05.227985_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 19_04_15.002675_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 19_04_15.002675_frames_automat")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001aed1e54460>)
```

To each 2 ordered rows, are correspondent files, the only difference in these files is the presence of the name "_automat" at the final of one of these files.
However, some of these files have different rows. For example, the files in line 17 have 16625 rows and the file in line 18 has 16660 rows.

I would like to separate the lines of these data.frame() where the number of rows is different for the correspondent files (with and without "_automat" in the name) in another data.frame().

output expected:

```
structure(list(number_of_cols = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), 
    number_of_rows = c(17258L, 17258L, 20059L, 20059L, 16943L, 
    16943L, 19090L, 19090L, 17846L, 17846L, 18879L, 18879L, 21076L, 
    21076L, 19978L, 19978L, 15938L, 15938L), name_of_file = c("Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 00_34_52.441983_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 01_35_01.902191_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 01_35_01.902191_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 02_35_11.367056_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 02_35_11.367056_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 03_35_20.855642_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 03_35_20.855642_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 04_35_30.251926_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 04_35_30.251926_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 05_35_39.708837_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 05_35_39.708837_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 06_35_49.255905_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 06_35_49.255905_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 07_35_58.696052_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 07_35_58.696052_frames_automat", "Basler_2020-12-01 19_04_15.002675_frames", 
    "Basler_2020-12-01 19_04_15.002675_frames_automat")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001aed1e54460>)
```

and/or:

```
structure(list(number_of_cols = c(20L, 20L), number_of_rows = c(16625L, 
16660L), name_of_file = c("Basler_2020-12-01 18_04_05.227985_frames", 
"Basler_2020-12-01 18_04_05.227985_frames_automat")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001aed1e54460>)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
A[, same := uniqueN(number_of_rows)==1, by=sub("_automat$", "", name_of_file)]

df1 = A[(same),][, same := NULL]
df2 = A[!(same),][, same := NULL]
A[, same := NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` package , where df1 is your first data.frame and df2  is the second

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df |> group_by(number_of_rows , number_of_cols) |> mutate(n = n()) |> filter(n == 2) |> select(-n)

df2 <- df |> group_by(number_of_rows , number_of_cols) |> mutate(n = n()) |> filter(n == 1) |> select(-n)
```

Comment: Great. It works well. Although a hypothetical situation where I could have one row that has a similar value in the number_of_rows column, but there belongs to another name_of_file column, would provide wrong information. Not?

Comment: I try it with a little variation, using stringr in group_by. However not work well, because creates another column.
`df2 <- df %>%  
  group_by(str_remove(name_of_file, "_automat"))  %>%  
  mutate(n = n()) %>%  
  filter(n == 1) %>%  
  select(-n)`

Comment: Try the above update with your hypothesis, it will work for each number_of_cols either.